# Keyboard broken on web app on Android devices

Tags: jquery, cordova, html-framework-7

When focus on input, the keyboard should be opened unless I tap somewhere out of input field and keyboard. It works fine on iOS, but on Android the keyboard disappears after every focus. Also, when I scroll, the keyboard disappears. But on ios everything is ok.
What should I do?
Web app used Framework7

Answer (score 0):

When using cordova on Android, I advise you to install crosswalk webview to achieve a consistent look and feel on all devices. I have had weird application behavior in the past when developing applications using *ionic 2* (uses cordova). I solved them by installing crosswalk-lite.

**According to crosswalk's github page:**

**Benefits**

- WebView doesn't change depending on Android version
- Capabilities: such as WebRTC, WebAudio, Web Components
- Performance improvements (compared to older system webviews)

**Drawbacks**

- Increased memory footprint
- An overhead of ~30MB (as reported by the RSS column of ps)
  Increased APK size (about 17MB)
  Increased size on disk when installed (about 50MB)

Install it using the following command: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`

Note: Crosswalk Lite is approximately half the size of regular Crosswalk

[Crosswalk WebView Cordova Plugin](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview)

[Crosswalk Lite](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/crosswalk_lite.html)

Comment: The keyboard is ok, but it disappears for example when I scroll. I want that keyboard stays opened when I scroll(if on input)

Comment: so I tried with something like window.onKeyboardOpen(); but i am lost